# ASP "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub "

Tags: asp-classic, parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525668/cannot-use-parentheses-when-calling-a-sub)

As far as I am aware this is correct but i get the error "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub"
Never used ASP before...can anyone shed light o nthe issue for me? code:

```
<%TESTWeb1.RecentlyViewedDisplay("Recently Viewed Header","Recently Viewed Entry","Recently Viewed Group Entry")%>
```

Comment: Here's an answer to another question that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525668/cannot-use-parentheses-when-calling-a-sub/1525752#1525752.  In particular, I found the links informative.

Answer (score 6):

In VB6 type languages you only need parentheses when calling a function, or when calling a sub using the `Call` keyword.

e.g.

```
DoSoemthing "foo","baa"

Call DoSomething("foo","baa")

myVar = DoSomething("foo","bar")
```

I think in your case taking the parentheses out of the call should work (although I can't check as I don't have an ASP configured environment handy.

Comment: Unfortunately just removing them does not work - I get an "Argument not optional" error instead.

Comment: @Bob, that means you've missed out an argument.  Taking the parentheses out *is* the fix for the error in the OP, looks like that has just opened a new error.